# trouble with obtaining user location via gps from htc wildfire s

Tags: android, gps, location

i wantto get user location with gps here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double lat=location.getLatitude();
            double longt= location.getLongitude();


            Geocoder gc=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
               try
               {
                   List <Address> adresses=gc.getFromLocation(lat, longt, 1);
                   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                   if(adresses.size()>0)
                   {
                       Address address=adresses.get(0);
                       for(int i=0;i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                           sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                       sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                       sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                       sb.append(address.getCountryName());

                   }

                   String a="Latitude:"+lat+"\nLongtitude:"+longt+"\nAddress:"+sb.toString();
                   t.setText(a);
               }

               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   t.setText("Error.\n"+e.toString());
               }
        }
```

and i gave all permissions;

platform is  Android 2.2.3 and device is HTC Wildfire S

code does not throws an error but it is not working either

has anyone any idea?

Comment: Could you define "is not working"? Are you waiting long enough for a GPS fix? Does `t` change? How is it not working?

Comment: t does not change and log cat shows nothing and i waited for GPS for 20-30 minutes...GPS icon on the top of the device is blinking and shows that device can get gps signals

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed, with a free app or anything, that you should have received a GPS location? Sometimes I don't get a location fix for 30 min, 60 min, 2 hrs... even if I have gotten one before in the same location. Where I am I *never* get a fix indoors; however I will get a fix if I walk around outside and then go back inside.

You code executes fine on my HTC (after walking outside). Though this doesn't affect anything now, I would recommend changing:

```
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

to:

```
MyLocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

as you make MyLocationListener more complex.